# How do I type the kanji for ちゆうごく (China)?

Tags: kanji, typesetting

I am very new to Japanese. I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I am using Mac OS and for some reason, whenever I type ちゆうごく　I am suggested something like 治癒動く as opposed to 中国 (I had to look that up and copy and paste it to type it here). How do I type this kanji?

Comment: Because it's not ちゆごく it's ちゅうごく

Comment: @user27223 Thats what I typed :(

Comment: it's ちゅう (chuu) not ちゆう (chiyuu) with a small ゅ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that there's a difference between ゆ and ゅ, つ and っ, etc. If you're using a non-Japanese keyboard your IME input's probably going to be romaji input, so thinking about it in romaji may be the easiest way to learn how to type. The "yu" sound you're hearing in China isn't actually "yu," but rather "chu" (a combination of ち and ゆ) - a sound that's represented as ちゅ in kana. Consequently, if you type in "chiyu" you're going to get ちゆ which is incorrect.

Comment: In a lot of IMEs you can get the small characters by putting an 'x' in front of the character. For example, 'yu' = ゆ / 'xyu' = ゅ. But generally, you only do this in specific cases (e.g. you want to write a glottal stop っ without being followed by a consonant).